# Issue closing a modal in bootstrap/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a button(findHotel) in my modal(travelModal) that will display a series of images and close/dismiss the modal at the same time.  This is my code.

html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="findHotel">Find Hotel</button>
```

and js

```
$("#findHotel").click(nySearch);
function nySearch () {
  if (true) {};
  document.getElementById("nyResults").style.display = "block";
  }
  $ ("#travelModal").modal("hide");
});
```

It displays the images, but it doesn't hide/close the modal.  I looked the bootstrap docs and that seems like it should work.  Can anyone explain what's wrong?

Comment: if #findHotel is a dynamically added DOM element, use "on" + click instead of "click" function.

Comment: @bhargavponnapalli: the click function works for the nySearch function though, so why wouldn't it also work for the `("hide")` method?

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: @vel it's pretty basic.  just a button in the modal

Comment: Cool, but without it, it's impossible to help. In other words, without anything complete or concrete, it's tough to help. Plus your function closes before the `"hide"` call, so we're not sure what you're doing.

Comment: @DaveNewton is right. Are you sure you didn't add an extra `}`? Also, what's the point of `if (true) {};` ?

Comment: @nem  deleted the `if` part, it wasn't needed.
@DaveNewton  i'm trying to make clicking the findHotel button A: display the `("nyResults")` and B: close the modal that contains it `(travelModal)`

The button is not created dynamically, nor is the modal.  I found a work-around by adding `data-dismiss="modal"` to the button in the HTML.  Thanks guys.